# "Missing" motor

Tags: subaru, power, forester

My Subaru Forester 2003 runs fine until I go up steep inclines when it starts to loose power and goes into "limp mode" (ie shut down). I can restart it okay but the same thing happens after a while and especially if I give it too much acceleration up hill. I have had all 4 spark plugs replaced last week.

What could it possibly be please?

Hot oil?

Fuel problem?

Spark leads?

Please help. I'd really appreciate it
Helen

Comment: any codes?  Typically an ECU goes into limp mode when it cannot reliably read an important sensor, like cam position or MAP/MAF.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the incline that is causing the problem and not just that you are having to put more than normal load on the engine?  If you were to try to accelerate quickly on the flat in a higher gear than normal, would the problem occur then?

Comment: Are you sure it's limp mode or is the engine just shutting off? I am not aware of any limp modes that shut off the engine. There is most likely a fuel issue like a plugged filter or weak fuel pump.

Comment: I've seen some pretty badly maintained/misfiring Subarus and have never encountered limp mode on one before. What's the service history on the car?

Comment: Are you (or the transmission) downshifting appropriately when going up the hill? Lugging the engine would cause it to stall, and I assume after a restart you (or the transmission) would shift into first. Possibly low transmission fluid preventing the transmission from shifting properly on a incline?

Comment: There is an engine light that is permanently on. Not sure abut the codes rpmerf, I did notice a strange noise when I was accelerating and the problem was worse when I accelerated hard, To describe it, it is like a lurching on acceleration. I have been told that "the oil" is over heating and causing the engine to shut down?

Comment: Ben, I was just told about the limp mode. You're right the engine cut out and the steering eventually locked too.. Do you think it is sucking air somewhere? Could this cause the problem? I am having it checked out today and will suggest things that you all have suggested. Thankyou so much. Great forum this!

Comment: Oh yeah, its an automatic trasmission...

Comment: It appears to be the oxygen sensor that is faulty. A new one will be put it on Monday. Fingers crossed this fixes the  problem. Thanks guys

Comment: An oxygen sensor failure would make sense regarding some of your symptoms.

Comment: Did the oxygen sensor resolve your issue?